# How to position a controller function's data output on a view in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

As I'm a beginner in MVC, I wanted to give CodeIgniter a try, a learnt the basics of the MVC pattern in PHP but there's a problem that I can't solve.

I have a "reference" function in my "Help" Controller that need to be outputed in a particular   place in a view. But, the data of the function actually output to the really top of the body.

What it gives me:
http://gyazo.com/1a17e9208c42f4b5d01e86ddad9a6d18

I need it to be to the left column.

My Help controller:

```
Class Help extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->view('help_reference_head_view');
    }

    function reference($perm_reference) {
        $this->load->model('help_model');
        $this->help_model->getReference($perm_reference);
    }
}
```

My help_model:

```
Class help_model extends CI_Model {

    function getReference($perm_reference) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('help');
        $this->db->where('perm_reference', $perm_reference);

        $q = $this->db->get();
        if($q->num_rows() == 1) {
            foreach ($q->result() as $key) {
                echo '<h2> ' . $key->perm_reference . '</h2>';
                echo $key->desc;
                $this->load->view('help_reference_footer_view');
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The help_reference_head_view file (The data ouput should be to the really bottom of this file, right after the col-md-9 div):
http://gyazo.com/60d52006d63c93f1a96613ce46db2024

Comment: CodeIgniter has nothing to do with MVC pattern, and only thing one should learn from it is "how not to write code" since codeigniter is filled with bad practices and examples of antipatterns. Also there is the minor fact, that EllisLab (which was producing said framework) is no longer maintaining CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head you could probably create a master template and load multiple views based on the controller response.

### Controller

```
class Helper extends CI_Controller
{
    public $template;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->template = 'layout/default'; //views/layout/default

        $this->load->model('help_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $reference = $this->help_model->getRef( $permissions );

        if(!$reference){
            return show_404();
        }

        return $this->load->view($this->template, array(
            'view'  =>   'help/index',
            'sidebar'  =>  $this->load->view('sidebar/index', array( 'data' => $reference), true)
        ));
    }
}
```

### Model

```
class Helper_Model extends CI_Model
{
    public function getRef( $permissions )
    {
        $this->db->select() // prolly don't need this as it will return * by default
                 ->from('help')
                 ->where('perm_reference', $permissions);

        $responce = $this->db->get();

        return ($responce->num_rows() > 0 ) ? $responce->result : false;
    }
}
```

### Master View (views/layout/default)

```
<section>
    <?php echo $this->load->view($view); ?>
</section>

<aside role="sidebar">
    <?php if($sidebar) : ?>
    <div class=help>
        <?php echo $this->load->view($sidebar); ?>
    </div>
     <?php endif; ?>
    <div>
        //default sidebar stuff
    </div>
</aside>
```